# Read Multiple File and process in SpringBoot + Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using Spring batch with spring boot. I am facing problems while processing multiple files.

My Scenario. I have multiple files having different headers, for example:

Sourcefile1.txt:

```
name, age, salary
ajay, 22, 2000
vijay, 23, 3000
```

Sourcefile2.txt:

```
name, address
vijay, india
ajay, uk
```

I want to process these files using spring boot with spring batch. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a spring batch job. 
Use a reader which will read the file, for reading csv files, there comes an 
implementation FlatFileItemReader from spring batch. While regsitering this class as a reader bean in spring batch, You can configure this file according to your need while performing the setter injection to it's properties.For example you can set a property linesToSkip of this class, which will exclude the lines which you do not want the spring batch to read, usually we skip the first line of the file as it contains the headers. further you can configure a line mapper to this bean for this there comes another implementation form spring batch itself having name DefaultLineMapper, extend this class if you want to customize your file mapping logic.
This is all about the reading part.Now further you can implement the processors and writers provided by spring batch for performing further actions on the data which you have read using the FlatFileReader.

Comment: Thanks Vijender for your comment. I am able to read one file and process too using spring batch. We are facing problem to read multiple files having different header at once and process.

Comment: In that case I think you should have a specific job for a particular file because these files are having different headers which means the files are not at all identical. Why would you want to process  heterogeneous files at once. Further you will face issues while processing these files In spring batch .

Comment: We have lot of sources who are sharing their data file with header with us. Now, we have to read all files and process into Database.

Comment: Do anyone having any idea to process multiple files having different header in Java? What is the best approach?